# Mercurial ACL, possible to grant a group permission to one branch but deny everything else?

Tags: mercurial, acl

Basically

```
[acl.groups]
group1=user1,user2
group2=user3,user4

[acl.allow.branch]
default=*

[acl.deny.branch]
*=@group2
```

Since Mercurial looks at deny first, it ignores acl.allow...our repo has many branches which are labeled with ticket numbers.  I can't possible deny each individual branch (and wild card matching on branches do not seem to work)

I would like to deny every branch to group2 but default

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure that the ACL extension sees the correct user? You can check this when you use `hg push --debug` to push into a local repo, or `hg serve --debug` when you push into a remote repo. Also note that the ACL extension does not use the user names from the commits, but the ones the OS or web server passes the server process.

Comment: Also note that you need to put an @ sign at the start of a group name when you use one.

Comment: ah, forgot the @ sign (this was just me mocking up a sample hgrc)..thanks for letting me know

Comment: Rudi  Does the mentioned scenario work for you?

Comment: I double checked the user names and they are correct and are in the correct group.  It seems that "deny=*" makes "default=*" moot

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I slept over the problem, and found the solution: You don't need to black list groups in your configuration, since you already have a white list. The white list works that way, that when it is present and no user entry matches, the user is denied ([src](http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/19a7b48446e3/hgext/acl.py#l236)). So you only need a white list, where default branch is permitted to all users, and all other branches are permitted to the branch people only. Since the non-branch people are not listed in the white list, they don't have permissions on them.

```
[acl.groups]
group1=user1,user2
group2=user3,user4

[acl.allow.branch]
default=*
*=@group1
```